# Print a block of a view under another view

Tags: 7, views, blocks

**Story:**

People can add Buildings, These buildings got fields (place, width etc.)
This one has a view called Buildings(page)

People can also add concepts for these buildings (name of concept, Concept description, dropdown in which you can select the building the concept is for.)
This one has a view called Concepts(page)

**What I wish to accomplish:**

On a specific building page, I wish to print a block underneeth the building info, which prints all the concepts titles(these redirect to the concept) created for that building.

I have been fighting around with taxonomy-terms and tons of other modules. the force just isn't with me today.

Is there anyone that could point me into the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any sort of reference to connect the building with the concept? If you have a reference be it entity or otherwise you should be able to use views contextual filters to build your relationship based on the node id of your building.

Comment: There is a relation between concept and building through an entity reference, within the contextual filters of the views.